# Laravel 4 Prevent Authenticated users from viewing other user profiles

Tags: php, laravel-4, restful-authentication

I am wondering how in `laravel 4` the following is possible. I have a filter to check if a user is authenticate on all routes that have user/*. My filter works as it is suppose to but lets say that a user is logged in their `url` will look something like this `user/id`. How do I prevent an authenticated user from viewing another user?

Comment: You should have posted related code to get more specific answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `Auth` filter you can access the route parameter (`'user/{id}'`) and can check logged in user's `id` with the `id` passed in the `url` like

```
Route::filter('auth', function($route)
{
    // get the id from rouqe
    $id = $route->getParameter('id');
    if( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->id != $id) {
        // not authenticated user, so access is denied
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

another approach is to change your urls..
why have url like user/{id} ?
just change it to for example

```
 user/profile
```

and inside the controller do something like:

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

that way the user just cant fake is id..
i only use urls with the id in the admin area where i need to edit some user:

```
/admin/{id}/edit
```

Comment: But in my application i have users who can creat and edit their profiles so their route look like this user/profile/id/edit. Out of curiosity could I have the url look something like this user/profile/username ?   @amirbar

Comment: why do you need their id in the url? you dont need their username either, in your controller you can get their id like so: $id = Auth::User()->id and change your url to: /user/profile/edit and put filter in routes to auth so if user is not logged in he will redirect to login @elodev

Answer (score 3):

If it is a blanket policy that a user can only view their own profile then could you just check that the id from user/{id} route matches the current user id from the login session, eg. in the profile controller something like:

```
public function getProfile($profile_id) {
    if (Auth::user()->id != $profile_id) {
        //this is not your profile - don't be nosey!
    } else {
        //have you got nothing better to do than look at yourself all day!
    }
}
```

Glen